# Часть модулей в NS3 не собралась

Tags: сеть, cygwin

Я работаю в Windows 7, но волею судьбы должен работать с NS3. Потому я поставил эмулятор Cygwin, в который успешно следуя инструкциям с оф. сайта установил NS3. Правда шесть модулей не смогли собраться:

```
Modules not built (see ns-3 tutorial for explanation):
brite                     click                     fd-net-device
openflow                  tap-bridge                visualizer
```

Я думаю что это из-за того, что я не стал ставить всё при установке Cygwin. Эмулятор можно переставить, доустановив всё необходимое, однако мне нужно знать что именно требуется NS3 для работы. Я нашёл на оф. сайте pdf-файл с туториалом, однако там представлено просто те же шаги инсталляции и тот же самый совет: мол, ищи в туториале. Причём в этом туториале кроме инструкций по установке и примеров больше ничего нет! Где можно найти необходимую информацию, т.е. что нужно чтобы эти модули собрались нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, эти 6 модулей **на данный момент принципиально** не могут быть собраны в Cygwin. Если вам необходимо их использовать, то придётся воспользоваться средствами виртуализации (типа Oracle Virtual Box). Если нет -- всё норм.

Подробнее на [английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927265/where-can-i-read-what-ns3-module-needs-to-be-built).